# Semi Supervised Learning without label propagation

Tags: python, clustering, word2vec, semi-supervised-learning

I am trying to cluster some words by affinity.
Using Word2Vec I obtained vector representation of every word that I can cluster with a normal unsupervised method.

Of these words, though, I know the classification of some of them, for example I know:

`Colors` group ==> `red`, `blue`, `yellow`
`Gender` group ==> `man`, `woman`

`UNKNOWN` ==> `shoes`, `brown`, `beautiful`.

As the example shows, `brown` should be categorized as a `Color`, but `shoes` and `beautiful` should be different clusters.

How could I use this information to create a semi-supervised model in order to cluster every word?

---

While the question is generic, I actually tried to create a program in Python, I tried the scikit methods `sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelSpreading` and `sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelSpreading`.
These, though, are not what I need since they only assign the known labels to the remaining objects, meaning that I would end up only with my `Colors` and `Gender` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy that seems good here is instance-level constrained clustering. These methods are semi-supervised algorithm that have "must-link" and "cannot-link" constraints between instances of known labels. So in your example, you would bind the 4 pairs (red, blue), (red, yellow), (blue, yellow), and (man, woman) as "must-link", and the 6 pairs (red, man), (red, woman), ..., (yellow, woman) as "cannot-link".

The results are similar to unsupervised clustering. For example, if you were to use DBSCAN (ignoring the labels/constraints), you would not need to specify the number of clusters/groups you're trying to achieve, and the algorithm would even find "outliers".

In fact, there is a version of DBSCAN that supports instance-level constraints, called C-DBSCAN. It is described in the work "Density-based semi-supervised clustering" by Ruiz et al (2010).

I do not know of any out-of-the-box implementations available, but I have a working version of C-DBSCAN I implemented for an experiment. However it is not documented nor is it performant/production level. You can find it at my [lab's repository](https://github.com/MaLL-UFSCar/CDenStream) if you're interested (also contains the C-DenStream, which is the data streams version of it, but it does not seem to fit your problem).

Comment: I found constrained clustering very interesting, though I did not find many implementations to try it